# Hyperledger fabric discovery service CLI

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

i am using hyperledger fabric-samples basic network I've modified network with 2 organization and 4 peer everything works fine but when i use discover cli it returns null.

```
peer0.org1.example.com (anchor peer)
peer1.org1.example.com
peer0.org2.example.com (anchor peer)
peer0.org2.example.com
./discover --configFile conf.yaml peers --channel mychannel  --server peer0.org1.example.com:7051
```

conf.yaml file contains userKey and userCert for peer0.org1.example.com

i have updated anchor peer for both organizations in the channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define an external endpoint for your peer, as discovery only reveals peers that have external endpoints.

Add to the [docker-compose.yaml](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.2/basic-network/docker-compose.yml) file:

- CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.example.com:7051

And it should work.

Comment: Yes i'm able to ping peer0.org1.example.com from CLI, and using discover cli inside CLI container. i have also installed and instantiated chaincode on peer0.org1.example.com and i'm able to query it from peer0.org2.example.com and other peers.
 i'm not using TLS is it mandatory to use..?

Comment: So - using discovery CLI inside the CLI container works, but outside doesn't work?

Comment: No, discovery CLI inside the CLI container does not work. i haven't tried outside.

Comment: can you please attach to your question description - a screen shot of what you try to do, and what you see? of your terminal, etc.

Also - the fabric samples use TLS so you need to use TLS too... to make the discover CLI use TLS you need to configure TLS CA certificates via the --peerTLSCA flag. Don't worry about the other tls flags for now.

Comment: Please check the video I've tried demonstrating my steps. https://youtu.be/BLwKt90CoT8  (video). as well as pasted my config file on below URL'S https://pastebin.com/raw/710Tz6yL (docker-compose.yaml) https://pastebin.com/raw/W7z9BaDd (configtx.yaml) https://pastebin.com/raw/uRduAV3q (crypto-config.yaml). and i'm using basic network in fabric samples it doesn't uses TLS, BYFN uses TLS i have tried running discovery service CLI from CLI in BYFN network it works fine(using --peerTLSCA in discovery service). but not able to reproduce same with basic network without TLS.

Comment: Found the problem. Updated my answer accordingly.